# How to select from partitioned table except a version in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-partitioning

[image]

My data set have a partitioned table and I have select all from them:
Select Customer id
from Company.database.Customer_*

- various from (2022-01-01 till today)
  But have a error version on 2022-06-08 and I dont want to select this version?

I tried
Select Customer id
from Company.database.Customer_*[^20220608] but well doesnt work

Comment: why not remove the wrong version or exclude in the where clàuse

Comment: it contains 1 error column but others still value

Comment: the where clause should remove the row(s), when you can identify it.

Comment: I've tried: WHERE
 _PARTITIONDATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('') AND TIMESTAMP('') but it Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONDATE

Comment: try _PARTITIONTIME

Comment: yep thank you I've tried _PARTITIONTIME same time with _PARTITIONDATE but still Unrecognized

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer:

```
Company.database.Customer_TABLE_SUFFIX >= 
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```